# why does character such as "\" error in c#

Tags: c#

I have a textbox that has a value depends on the Path of the file after dragging the folder. the return value of dragged folder is `"C:\Program Files"`.
and I want to add the char `"\"` on the textbox, but if I add that character, there is an error such as red line below my code, the example of a red line is when you misspelled a word in a document.

code:

`txtResult.Text + "\" + textFile + ".txt"`

Question:

what is the main reason that this string value does have an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inside a string the backslash character `'\'`, it is interpreted as an escape character.

In your case it's `escaping` the `double quote`, which is nesseccary when you want a double quote character inside a quoted string. However since you want the literal backslash, you should escape the backslash, which Means:

Use `"\\"`.

Now it will produce a single backslash.

**Edit:**

Another option is to use an `@-quoted string`, like this:

```
@"\"
```

Now you don't have to escape the character.

Comment: You may also use verbatim string: `var path = @"C:\Program Files";`

Comment: thank sir :) got it :)